# Is there a way of getting the names of all subclasses

Tags: haxe

I want to get the names of all subclasses of a base class. From that I want to @:build an enum where every entry is the name of a class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. The order of macro executions is undefined, as specified in documentation.

[AutoBuildingMacro.hx]

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

final mapofnames = new Map<String,Array<String>>();

class AutoBuildingMacro {
  public static macro function fromBaseClass(base):Array<Field> {
    var parent = haxe.macro.ExprTools.toString(base);
    var names = mapofnames[parent];
    if ( names == null ) {
      names = new Array<String>();
      mapofnames[parent] = names;
    }
    names.push(Context.getLocalClass().toString());
    trace(mapofnames);
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Main.hx]

```
import AutoBuildingMacro;

class Main {
  static public function main() {}
}

@:autoBuild(AutoBuildingMacro.fromBaseClass(Parent))
class Parent {
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
}

class Child3 extends Child2 {
}
```

Output:

AutoBuildingMacro.hx:15: {Parent => [Child2]}

AutoBuildingMacro.hx:15: {Parent => [Child2,Child3]}

AutoBuildingMacro.hx:15: {Parent => [Child2,Child3,Child1]}

Comment: This isn't exactly what I need because it uses @:autoBuild to construct the array which makes it impossible to build an enum from the array. I think I still can use this for my purposes though. I'm sorry for having been so unspecific in my post earlier.

Comment: No problem. You can still solve this. First approach is to use two builds, first only triggers auto-build without generating source code, second is building enums and a source code. However, this approach requires completion server to be running (persistent variables). Other way is more sophisticated, requires advanced knowledge of the macros, will point you to the discussion about this once Haxe Community forum is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for auto-build macro feature https://haxe.org/manual/macro-auto-build.html
And then enum building https://haxe.org/manual/macro-enum-building.html

Comment: Thank you but I already know about build macros, the reason I mentioned them is because it needs to be available at that stage. The important part is the "getting the names of all subclasses".

Comment: Sorry, but your terminology confuses me. In above link there is a Base->Main class inheritance, e.g. Main class extends Base class. In other words, Main class is a subclass of the Base class. However, you maybe want to know from which class is Main derived? I don't think that is possible, although Haxe doesn't support multiple inheritance (last time I checked Haxe, more than a year ago)

Comment: Sorry if I explained it badly. I'll see if I can explain better. Let's say we have a class "Parent". Parent is extended by class "Child1" and "Child2". Child2 is extended by Child3. I want to apply a function to Parent that gives me an array that looks like this `["Child1", "Child2", "Child3"]`.

Comment: You asked if it is possible. Yes, it is. Now it seems you are asking for source code instead. Please be specific while asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called [compiletime](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime) that has this feature:

```
// Returns a list of all the classes that inherit MySuperClass, no matter what package
CompileTime.getAllClasses(MySuperClass);
```

The [approach](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime/blob/master/src/CompileTime.hx#L122) I took worked around the build order problem by using the Context.onGenerate hook to build an array of matching classes at the end of compilation (rather than as each class is compiled) and add the array to “metadata”, which can still be modified in the “onGenerate” step. I then use this metadata in a separate runtime class to get the array of classes at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that is advanced macros usage: onAfterTyping, onGenerate, onAfterGenerate are powerful. Thanks for writing this library.